npm install fails in Azure Pipeline
I am confused...
We have build pipelines for several projects running on self-hosted build agents on a single server. All pipelines are setup the same:

checkout from GIT
install Node
npm authenticate
Build solution
...

In all solutions nearly the same npm packages are referenced, maybe with some version differences. Two packages are coming from our own Azure DevOps feed. The .npmrc of the solution is always pointing to our feed via https.
The builds all run with no problems.
I started now setting up a new server with new build agents. Certificates of the Azure DevOps server are installed. When I run the builds now on the new agents, one project is building and in all others I get the following error when npm install --ignorescripts gets called:
  npm install --ignore-scripts
  npm ERR! code E401
  npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.
  npm ERR! To correct this please trying logging in again with:
  npm ERR!     npm login

When I clone the repository manually on that server and run npm install it works fine (I have added tokens to my users .npmrc of course).
Does anyone have an idea where to look at?
Update #1
This is the YAML of the npm authenticate task:
steps:
- task: npmAuthenticate@0
  displayName: 'npm Authenticate Code/<project>/.npmrc'
  inputs:
    workingFile: Code/<project>/.npmrc

<project> is the name of the project inside the solution and is the same as the relative path.
The .npmrc looks always like this:
@<ourscope>:registry=https://<azdoserver>/tfs/<collection>/_packaging/<feed>/npm/registry/
always-auth=true

Update #2
It turned out that the project which successfully built, was already built on the new agent referencing the npm registry in the .npmrc using http and after that it was changed to https.
In other words, the build agent is using cached packages instead of getting fresh ones from the registry.
Now the question is: What else do I have to do to get the packages from the registry over https?

Do you mean you tried to run the same pipelines on the new agents, which used to work on the old ones?

Was the npm feed defined in .npmrc a collection or project scope feed?

Can you share a minimal reproducible YAML context to help understand the pipeline workflow configurations? What are differences in the YAML definition and the .npmrc files between the succeeded and failed builds?

@AlvinZhao-MSFT exactly, the same pipelines aren't running on the other agents. the feed is collection scope.

By When I run the builds now on the new agents, one project is building, is there any difference in the YAML definition and the .npmrc files between the succeeded and failed builds on the new agents?

@AlvinZhao-MSFT I have added our .npmrc and yaml above. The differences between the  pipelines are the path to .npmrc .

Did you configure the agent before or after you setup https connection to the server? Was the server URL resolvable on that agent machine now?

The agent was already setup before changing to https. The server URL itself is resolvable.

Would you have a test to configure a new agent from a different path on the same machine? You can input the https://server/url when asked. Then test to run the npm install command on this new agent.

I suspect the agent service couldn't resolve the server URL, because the server used to use http URL, which was input during the agent setup.

Even with a newly setup agent the same error appears.

You input the new HTTPS server URL to configure the new agent right? What if you run npm install command directly in your nodejs app directory on that machine?

I mentioned that already in the description "When I clone the repository manually on that server and run npm install it works fine (I have added tokens to my users .npmrc of course)."

Just want to confirm if the agent service is running as the same user account as your local user which works.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT After cross-checking the failed builds I have seen that the last build was not running on the new agent which was setup with https. I retested it now with two projects and it seems to run now on https.
Thanks for your help!

Glad to know the issue was resolved and thanks a lot for your sharing, which may help others with similar concerns. Cheers!
